# Carregar o conteúdo de uma <TD> em outra <TD> ADVPL ASP

Tags: html, advpl

Estou com uma dúvida em um código que utiliza de advpl(Microsiga Protheus) mais HTML.

Estou precisando na parte html,  que o conteúdo de uma TD seja capturado no momento da escrita, e seja atribuído em outra TD.
Segue abaixo a captura de tela mais o trecho do código:

[image: Registro de Notas de saída]

Nesse caso preciso que ao fazer a coleta da chave da Nota, autocomplete o Numero da NF e série  pegando o SUBSTRING 26,9 número da nf  e 23,3  Série da NF.

Código html

```
<CENTER><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#ff0080"><b>REGISTRO DE NF DE SAIDA</b></font></CENTER>

         <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#F3F3F3" width="400" id="AutoNumber10">
          <tr>
            <td width="120"><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000080"><b>&nbsp;Chave Da NF:</b></font></td>&nbsp;
            <td width="161"><input type="text" name="T2" size="44" MAXLENGTH="44" onblur="jscript:valida(this.value);"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="120"><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000080"><b>&nbsp;Numero NF:</b></font></td>&nbsp;
            <td width="161"><input type="text" name="T3" VALUE=" " size="6"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="120"><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000080"><b>&nbsp;Serie NF:</b></font></td>&nbsp;
            <td width="161"><input type="text" name="T4" VALUE=" " size="3"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="120"><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#000080"><b>&nbsp;Status:</b></font></td>&nbsp;
            <td width="161">
                <select size="1" name="STATUS">
                    <option value="S">1= Saída na Portaria</option>
                    <option value="D">2= Devolvido para Estoque</option>
                    <option value="C">3= Cancelamento Cliente</option>
                </select>
            </td>
          </tr> 
        </table>  <br>
        <button name="B1" type="none" onclick='jscript:validaall()'>> Confirma <</button>
        </center> <br>
        <center><a href='H_W10_03_NOVO.APL'><i><b>Voltar ao Menu</b></i></a></center>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </center>
```

Já deixo meus agradecimentos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Obrigado siga0984..

Consegui resolver, seguindo sua dica tive uma ideia, ao invés de criar o formulário, na função valida, onde já temos os dados carregados, passei uma substring do conteúdo do campo da chave da nota fiscal **para o (value)** do outro campo.
Como no html além da validação do JavaScript como você mencionou,também é passado a função **onblur** ao clicar fora do campo automaticamente é carregado o campo Numero NF e Série NF.
Segue o trecho do código para melhor entendimento:

```
<script> 

function valida(xx)

{

if(xx=='')

alert(' Campo não pode ser vazio !'); 

else

document.form1.T3.value = xx.substr(25,9);

document.form1.T4.value = xx.substr(22,3);

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu código Html, já está sendo usado JavaScript para fazer a validação da chave da nota fiscal ( função javacript:valida() , disparada após a perda do foco no campo "Chave da NF" ), e a validação "total" através da função validaall(), disparada através do botão "Confirma".

O que você vai atualizar não é exatamente as "TDs" das tabelas, mas os valores dos INPUTs dispostos na tabela. Para fazer estes eventos, eu criaria um formulário HTML para agrupar os inputs, passando este formulário como parâmetro para a função valida() em Javascript, e dentro dela faria a quebra do valor do campo e alimentação dos valores dos demais inputs do formulário.

Existe um tópico (em inglês) no próprio StackOverflow -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field -- mostrando alternativas de como fazer o preenchimento de um campo de formulário ou INPUT Html usando JavaScript.